How to jsonb_build_object() in clickhouse?
I have this query in postgresql:
select t.id, t.hash, 
array_agg (distinct jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('field1', l.field1, 'value', l."value"))) logs_array,
array_agg (distinct jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('tag1', tg.tag1, 'value', tg."value"))) tags_array
from transactions t 
left join logs l on t.id = l.transaction_id 
left join tags tg on t.id = tg.transaction_id
where l.field1 = 'f1' and tg.tag1 = 't1'
group by t.id, t.hash
order by t.id;

how to convert it to clickhouse? array_agg I guess it's groupArray. What about jsonb_build_object?
Example:
transactions
 id int
 hash var

id | hash 
------------
1  |  h1
2  |  h2
3  |  h3

logs
 transaction_id int
 field1 var
 value var

transaction_id | field1 | value 
-------------------------------
1              | f1     | v1
1              | f2     | v2
2              | f3     | v3
3              | f4     | v4

tags
 transaction_id int
 tag1 var
 value var

transaction_id | tag1   | value 
-------------------------------
1              | t1     | v1
2              | t2     | v2
2              | t3     | v3

I need result:
id | hash | logs_array                                                         | tags_array
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | h1   | [{'field1': 'f1', 'value': 'v1'}, {'field1': 'f2', 'value': 'v2'}] | [{'tag1': 't1', 'value': 'v1'}]
2  | h2   | [{'field1': 'f3', 'value': 'v3'}]                                  | [{'tag1': 't2', 'value': 'v2'}, {'tag1': 't3', 'value': 'v3'}]
3  | h3   | [{'field1': 'f4', 'value': 'v4'}]                                  | []

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/42X7Dw3k2RbUe2MoJxmQET/6

I'll let you figure out the rest for tags but this should answer the question, groupArray and toJSONString. You need to cast to named tuples.
CREATE TABLE transactions
(
    `Id` Int32,
    `hash` String
)
ENGINE = Memory


CREATE TABLE logs
(
    `transaction_id` Int32,
    `field1` String,
    `value` String
)
ENGINE = Memory

INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (1, 'h1'), (2, 'h2'), (3, 'h3')
INSERT INTO logs VALUES (1, 'f1', 'v1'), (1, 'f2', 'v2'), (2, 'f3', 'v3'), (3, 'f4', 'v4')


SELECT
    Id,
    any(hash) AS hash,
    toJSONString(groupArray((field1, value)::'Tuple(field1 String, value String)')) AS logs_array
FROM transactions AS t
LEFT JOIN logs AS l ON t.Id = l.transaction_id
GROUP BY Id

Query id: 34c5e09d-1411-497b-903b-13a6ff76f10b

   ┌─Id─┬─hash─┬─logs_array──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
1. │  3 │ h3   │ [{"field1":"f4","value":"v4"}]                              │
2. │  2 │ h2   │ [{"field1":"f3","value":"v3"}]                              │
3. │  1 │ h1   │ [{"field1":"f1","value":"v1"},{"field1":"f2","value":"v2"}] │
   └────┴──────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.



Here is an other way to do it using toJSONString, groupArray and map :
SELECT t.id,
       toJSONString(groupArray(distinct map('field1', field1, 'value', l.val))) as logs_array,
       toJSONString(groupArray(distinct map('tag1', tag1, 'value', tg.val))) as tags_array
FROM transactions AS t
LEFT JOIN logs AS l ON t.id = l.transaction_id
LEFT JOIN tags tg on t.id = tg.transaction_id
GROUP BY t.id

